# How do I output incoming IRC Messages? (Twitch IRC) #JAVA

Tags: java, irc, twitch

Just so you know, this is my first stackoverflow question and I hope I dont make any mistakes ^^. (except some grammer mistakes, I'll try my best)

I'm trying to make a Twitch Bot in Java. I CAN connect to the server and I am also able to write messages to the server/chat. But the problem I have is that I dont know how to READ messages from the server/chat. I looked up for some help on how to read messages and output them in my console, which i have integrated in my GUI.

NONE of them worked.

I do have an inputStream and a BufferedReader but to be honest I dont even know what I really need. I'm new to Java (well, learning it 3 years now, but in school)

My goal is to output the IRC messages like that:

```
< PASS oauth:twitch_oauth_token
< NICK twitch_username
> :tmi.twitch.tv 001 twitch_username :connected to TMI
> :tmi.twitch.tv 002 twitch_username :your host is TMI
> :tmi.twitch.tv 003 twitch_username :this server is pretty new
> :tmi.twitch.tv 004 twitch_username tmi.twitch.tv 0.0.1 w n
> :tmi.twitch.tv 375 twitch_username :- tmi.twitch.tv Message of the day - 
> :tmi.twitch.tv 372 twitch_username :- not much to say here
> :tmi.twitch.tv 376 twitch_username :End of /MOTD command
```

I hope there is someone who can help me out!

If there are any question regarding my code, just tell me so I can give it to you. As i said, I'm new to stackoverflow and i never asked a question like that.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We'll probably need to see some of your code

Comment: When you say messages, do you mean actual messages, or protocol messages? EG: do you want JUST chat, or do you want user lists, topics, etc

Comment: Hi there. It probably would be a good idea to post some code illustrating what you have tried so far and expanding on the difficulties you are encountering. If you do that I'm sure there'll be plenty of people trying to help you out. Good luck.

Comment: @j.seashell what exactly do you need? There is not much I can provide except the declaration of the inputStream and BufferedReader. The rest of the code are just connecting, disconnecting, writing methods.

Comment: @zack6849 I would start with protocol messages. EDIT: i meant chat messages

Comment: @Sparky thank you very much!

Comment: You mention you join the chat server, but are you also joining a channel? Just making sure :P